# Tweepy on_status Trouble

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I am trying to stream all tweets tweeted in english monitoring for a keyword. I redefined the on_status function to do so. I get no errors when running the code, however for whatever reason the tweets aren't being printed, as is expected. I tweeted with the keyword from my own account to be sure. Any advice helps! Thanks in advance. LEt me know if there is any more information I can provide to clarify.

```
import tweepy
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['Twitter_DB']
collection_Authentication = db['authentication']

consumer_key = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name" : "consumer_key"})
["value"]
consumer_secret = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name" : 
"consumer_secret"})["value"]
access_token = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name" : "access_token"})
["value"]
access_secret = collection_Authentication.find_one({"name" : "access_secret"})
["value"]

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

#-----class StdOutListener() Definition-----

class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(str(status_code))
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print("Timeout...")
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track="ethereum", languages="en")
```

Comment: try `stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, listener)`?

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference, thanks though